# hal deploy apply failing on kubernetes cluster using halyard

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Need some help on deploying spinnaker on an existing AWS EKS cluster using halyard.
When we do a **hal deploy apply**, the deployment is with the readiness probe of **http://localhost:**, which is failing as the localhost will be the server from where I deploy spinnaker on the cluster.
So I updated the readiness probe (manually on the kubernetes deployment.yaml) to **tcpSocket: port:** .
When I try a redeploy with **hal deploy apply**, the issue arises for the conflicting readiness probe.

Has anyone faced this issue???? Are we missing/messing anything here?
Any help would be highly appreciated  & many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Armory guide for installing Spinnaker in EKS works great also with OSS version of Spinnaker. We've used for several installations and there were no issues like described one.

Follow the link - [Installing Spinnaker in AWS](https://docs.armory.io/spinnaker-install-admin-guides/install-on-aws/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my coredns, one of my coredns pods were failing & that caused few of the spinnaker pods to fail the readiness probe & I updated the readiness probe from my end. This was not required as I fixed the issue with my corerdns. Spinnaker installation worked smooth otherwise.